# Get other application path in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I have two application which is will installed on same PC. Usually client will install it on C:\Program Files , but sometime there are some user install it on D:\ F:\ or somewhere they like. So i'm struggling to get other app executable path.

For illustration :

- App 1 location : G:\App1 Folder\App1.exe
- App 2 location : C:\Program Files\App2 Folder\App2.exe

How i can get other App2 executable path on App 1 ("G:\App1 Folder\App1.exe") ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

`Dim strPath As String = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName( _
    System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase)` to get Executable directory when app runs and store into registery or some where else. 
[Ref.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa457089.aspx)

or

Ask user to locate executable during 1st run and save location to some place